# how to modify SASS CSS in visual studio?

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013, sass

I need to modify CSS in an existing MVC project. CSS it has is coming from multiple SASS files. I m just guessing correct way would be to do changes in SASS files and regenerate CSS from it. But I m not sure which extension or add in I should use for it. Can you please guide what tool/ or extension I should add in Visual Studio to do changes and regenerate .css file ?

I highly appropriate your guidance time and help.

Comment: The latest version of visual studio 2013 has some baked in sass support, but no compiler. To compile, install SassyStudio or Web Essentials 2013.

Comment: @DarrenKopp  I want to use SassyStudio, just a question please, is it easy, can you please give a little hint how generate one css file from multiple existing sass files. or please direct me to some source. Cheers.

Comment: I wouldn't care about multiple CSS files, if you simple install [Request Reduce](http://requestreduce.org/) nuget package and on production, it will minimize, and make only one CSS, plus, you have several [configuration options](https://github.com/mwrock/RequestReduce/wiki/RequestReduce-Configuration-options) including sprites, caching, cdn... etc

Comment: @user576510 hopefully this will explain a bit how things work: https://gist.github.com/darrenkopp/90fc356ec69f1830ff4f